# Img acting as button in HTML form submitting when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a simple image inside an HTML form that acts as a button. When a normal button is clicked I act upon that using the onClick attribute, but with my images when you click on them the onClick does work, but the image also submits the form, when it actually shouldn't.

My code:

```
<input type="image" id="button" value="Assign" src="/Images/rightarrow.png" alt="Assign Selected Rule" class="imgAssignUnassign" onclick="manageHandlers('Assign')" />
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifying the type attribute of an input as `image` makes it a submit button. Add `return false` to the onclick.

```
<input type="image" id="button" value="Assign" src="/Images/rightarrow.png" alt="Assign Selected Rule" class="imgAssignUnassign" onclick="manageHandlers('Assign');return false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong. It should according to [w3c docs](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/image).

To prevent that you could user preventDefault method of the event:

```
$('#button').click(function(e){
    //do something
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Sorry about that, you might have misunderstood me. It is so that it's "supposed to" according to the language specifications, I just didn't want it to. Was looking for a solution like Walkermeo gave. Thanks for the effort though

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using `<input type='image' />` 
If you just want a normal image use the `<img />` tag